# Where should hibernate libraries live on web server?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm deploying a hibernate web servlet app onto a cloud server. I read that hibernate libraries should not go into the webapp's lib folder.  I assume that means the hibernate jars should not be part of the war file?  So where should the hibernate libraries go?

Comment: they should be part of the war and be deployed in the folder: yourwebapp/WEB-INF/lib/

Comment: Which cloud?  Where did you read "hibernate libraries should not go into the webapp's lib folder"?  Without those answer it's hard to give a definitive answer.  It's possible the cloud environment is providing hibernate jars and expecting it's versions to be used.  If you include hibernate jars in WEB-INF/lib they might override the cloud provided version, potentially causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application server you are using.

For example, if you are using Tomcat, your libraries should go to `$CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib`

Because if you put them in the WAR : 
1- Your WAR file size will increased, 
2- If there's another application that uses the same lib, your lib would be loaded twice, and so on